# Keyboard shortcut for switching windows not working in Yosemite

Tags: keyboard, macos

While on OS X 10.9 it works nice to switch windows of all apps (not produced by apple) I am using in my work like Google Chrome, SublimeText, iTerm from keyboard using:

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

On OS X 10.10 it works only with apple apps ;(

Is there something changed, what third-party applications developers should change, or is some other keyboard shortcut to get this working as it should?

**UPDATE:**
- I restored all keyboard settings to default, and things started working as expected.

[image]

Make sure that this one checkbox is checked:

Comment: Cmd + ~ is still working in Yosemite to switch windows in non-Apple apps for me.

Comment: The key combination is cmd - ` rather than cmd - ~. Perhaps on your keyboard these symbols are not on the same key?

Comment: @amergin Indeed my mistake, I meant of course `\`` and not `~`. But this still does not work for me on non-apple apps ;(

Comment: This does not work for me. Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: **EDIT** It actually works but I had to press ⌘⇧ and the key next to backspace on my Swedish keyboard. Without ⇧ I get the ´ acute accent, not ` grave accent (or "backtick" as illiterates call it).

Comment: Nothing works for me since upgrading to Sonoma...

Comment: @vaughan did you restore to defaults? which language?

Comment: @andilabs English and did restore to defaults. No fix.

Answer (score 8):

It seems not to work in full screen mode of apps. Switching to normal mode everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had to uncheck "Move focus to next window", then recheck it. Then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences/keyboard/shortcuts/keyboard and then check box to the left of "Move focus to next window' [command `]

Before I checked box, there was no keyboard shortcut to cycle between open windows or tabs on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

After checking box, command` cycles between open windows/tabs in all browsers

Comment: Thank you! Mine was mapped to ⌘ F1 and I never set it to that. It must be something to do with region settings. Japanese region settings here on a US keyboard. (And previously used a Japanese keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

For MacBook Pro, the default settings are: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

But to access this shortcut from the keyboard, you need to press: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

This looks difficult as you need to press three keys together. So a better option would be to Go to **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Shortcuts** > **Keyboard**, and change the key combination for **Move focus to next window** to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> and enable the checkbox.

**It started working**

[image: Keyboard Settings settings to reset 'Move focus to next window' command]

Answer (score 0):

I've bought a Macbook Pro with german keyboard a couple of weeks ago. It came with Yosemite installed, I was looking for the same shortcut, I found that Cmd + < does the trick.

Comment: That seems to open settings on mine (standard keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different thing solved it for me. The checkbox was checked and the shortcut was `⌘ F1` but it wasn't working.
Changed the shortcut to a different one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when Stage Manager was on. Sometimes <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> worked, sometimes not. After disabling Stage Manager, the combination works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually toggle **Stage Manager**.

- Enable **Displays have separate spaces**
- Log out / log in
- Uncheck **Stage Manager** from the Menu Bar or the settings (it won't work unless you do this)
- Log out / log in
- It should work now